# Can one add React Keys after instantiation?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactjs, jsx

I’m making a collection of React Elements and displaying them; what follows is a trivial example to frame the problem of how-would-one-modify-an-preexisting-instantiated-element only.

```
var c = [
  <div>A</div>,
  <div>B</div>,
  // ...
  <div>Z</div>
];

var ListComponents = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>{c}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<ListComponents/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

While the code above “works,” it renders a console message I’d rather not ignore:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
>   Check the render method of `ListComponents`.
>   See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.

Superficially, I could just add a unique `key="…"` string to each element in `c` and be done with it.

However, that seems a quite verbose, especially since I have the data in an indexed array and a functional language that in theory can assign each key its matching index value without manually having to enter it as a source literal.

*I’d love to be able to just do this...*

```
c.forEach( (e,i) => e.key = i );        // ...or call some setter
```

### What’s the *right* React-way to do this -and- keep the code clean?

---

**ADDENDUM:**
*...for the curious or those that want to just say add a key field...*

The collection I'm using is actually an array of tuples containing meta-data and a corresponding React Element, a custom Component, or some huge JSX block. The example above overly trivializes what the actual data looks like as well as its irregularities.

As the source data itself is quite long, updated often, and not maintained by a developer; it is highly error prone to missed key fields or duplicates values from manual entry. Hence the desire to do it entirely programmatically. I can not count on the data owners to do it properly. They can't read code, so ideally I'd rather not mess up the data structures with a lot of "programming goop."

The collection is manipulated a few times, putting various runs of certain elements into other dynamically created wrappers, so that the final collection is actually generated by a few transformations, filters, and maps before it is ultimately displayed.

Comment: It's likely you cannot, since React freezes the element itself and its properties: `Object.freeze(element.props);
    Object.freeze(element);` https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/7b47e3e537c91bc5e43de087d831e4abf017ad96/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L107

Comment: Why don't you actually separate the data transformation and JSX generation steps? Prepare the array `c` first that only contains pure data, then render it with `c.map((v, i) => <div key={i}>{v}</div>)` in the component.

Comment: that's not "superficially", that's "following React's system for efficient diffing". React has no idea that you just declared a throw-away array, all it sees is you passing in a list of elements that it *needs* to efficiently diff on every `render()` call. It *needs* those keys to identify which element modifications happened in, even if you tell yourself you're never going to change them.

Comment: @zerkms -- the problem is that the folks entering the data _think_ they are entering in HTML and do not know programming, otherwise this is exactly how I'd approach the solution. Alas, the real data is heterogeneous and is not just DIVs as shown in the overly trivial example, but rather all sorts of elements including some custom tags made for them. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- I get that the React system needs the keys, which is why I'm trying to provide them, but what I'm getting at is rather than having the data suppliers provide the keys (which is highly error prone), I want the keys to be programmatically applied without error after they've given me a collection of the data. That's the actual goal, to help eliminate error with the added benefit of lessening the burden of data entry.

Comment: other way around. As system designer you are far better suited to determine which part of arbitrary complex data should count as uniquely identifying key for each chunk of data that you're `map()`ing. There is no algorithm in computing that can just "tell which thing is a valid, guaranteed unique key".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I think we're talking past each other, but are in basic agreement. While I've managed to get folks to provide simple "html" (actually JSX) in an ordered list, there's no way I can count on them to provide key="blah" fields without forgetting a key here or duplicating a key there. As all I'm trying to do is provide a unique key for all items in the collection, something the index does quite well, Wes Bos's solution lets them focus on what to say and the surrounding code how to say it. If they bork a manual key, they won't know enough to fix it. I may not be around.

Comment: the problem with that approach, however, is that the index *is not* uniquely identifying. If it identifies *different* elements when you use `map()` vs `sort().map()`, your key is a false key, and you're adversely affecting React's ability to efficiently do virtual DOM diffing. If you're fine with that, then there is no problem, but if you want to do things "right", you can't use array positions to uniquely identify items, because they can't. They say nothing about the entry in any way, they only say something about the list the entries are in. Or just ignore the warning, that works too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I totally see where you're going with this this.  In the highly specialized code that I'm working with, I'm merely accepting a single constant array for one-time one-use one-purpose initialization from a bunch of non-technical text-entry folks. If the array itself were actually a "real" collection even in the vaguest sense of the word, then absolutely, this is NOT the thing to do and manual entry of keys would be mandatory (or something better generate them better than an index position). For this case, where the array is used and throw away, it works. Good point!

Answer (score 1):

A major shout out to [Wes Bos](http://wesbos.com), who came up with a clever solution that works!

The code is a simple one liner and does exactly what I was looking for:

```
c = c.map( (el,key) => React.cloneElement(el, {key} ));
```

We're building a new collection using the **.cloneElement()** method, which I was unaware of.  That was what I needed, it turns out.

In the **.map()** operation, the lambda function is passed both the element and the *index*.  It's return value is a cloned element, but with the key property set.

By cleverly naming the index element `key`, it allows the short notation for the expression `{ "key" : key }`.  This object augments the cloned object.

In the end, I end up with a new collection of identical objects, each with a key property set to the index.

Comment: note that this is not a good solution in terms of what React needs: keys are used for virtual DOM diffing, and should uniquely identify the element you're creating, which array positions don't. For instance, with a proper key, going from `map()` to `sort().map()` will make React just move some nodes around with virtually no overhead, because all it sees is a reodering of the keys. With array position keys, you've told React to modify the internal properties and fully rerender all entries, because if you consider the keys "the stable id", then based on those keys *all the content changed*

Comment: For those following along, my interest was to know how to add keys after the fact -- cloneElement is the solution. For my specific high case which is highly specialized, I use the input array ONCE to generate a set of components ONCE and do -not- treat it as a container nor dynamic in any way. Follow Mike's lead above and AVOID using an array's index as the key, under normal circumstances this is *not* the right thing to do. The problem example is deliberately over-trivialized and focuses only on the concept of "modifying" pre-constructed elements. This is NOT real-world application code!